# Android Studio: Why Changing App Name starts causing Unresolved Reference Errors?

Tags: android, android-studio, compiler-errors, compilation

I am a total newbie (medical doctor). I had some friends create an app for my patients, which I want to offer for free to poor patients, via Play Store. For some reason I have to change the name of the app (Google removed all apps that had the word Corona). However while I can compile the old version, I get the following errors when I change the name (Refactoring).Any suggestions?

Note: I do get a warning re android-kotlin-extension Gradle deprecation (but that is so even before I make the app name refactoring)

[image: Image showing compile errors - Unresolved References in several fragment files]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are sure what you are doing I would tell you to stay away from the code refactoring, leave the code be.

Your friends must have created a [Google Play Console Account](https://play.google.com/console/developers) to upload the app to Play Store.

You need to access this account, select the affected app, under ***Store Presence*** you will find a tab for ***Main Store Listing*** and from here you will be able to change the name as shown on this Screenshot.
[image]

The proposed name should not be more than 50 Characters and should not have Emojis.
Remember to Save Changes for approval by Google.

PS. You can ignore the warning about android-kotlin-extension deprecation.